# Batch file query

Tags: windows-7, drivers, batch

Would anyone know why on Windows7 Enterprise the below line of code from a Batch file creates a blank 0KB html file with no data. It works fine on a Windows10 machine.

`wmic sysdriver list full /format:htable > "%WINDIR%\CCM\%COMPUTERNAME%/%COMPUTERNAME%-drivers.unicode.html"
type "%WINDIR%\CCM\%COMPUTERNAME%\%COMPUTERNAME%-drivers.unicode.html" > "%WINDIR%\CCM\%COMPUTERNAME%/%COMPUTERNAME%-drivers.html"`

Thanks,

Comment: I used to be pretty good at batching, however, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's a line of code in a batch file that pulls a list of drivers installed on a machine and redirects it to a HTML file. The newly created HTML file comes out blank with a size of 0KB, however, the line of code works fine on Windows10.

Comment: I removed the comment now. Hope it's better now.

Comment: I Just tested this on my computer, I ran it from CMD (admin) __wmic sysdriver list full /format:htable > TEST.HTML__  It came out okay.

Comment: Did you test it on Windows10?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, yes.  I opened the command prompt to my desktop. From system32 folder I type __cd "C:\users\my computer\desktop"__

Comment: It works on Windows10 but not on Windows7. I dont think i can comment further here becasue Stack Exchange is complaining about not having extended discussions in the comments section. Thanks for the help @vssher.

Comment: My html file did not come with head, title, or body, I added it to the file though. Windows 10 is more advanced. I am glad it worked for you on at least one. PEACE

Comment: @ShidoshiTanaka Stack Exchange is not complaining, it is suggesting that it can be moved to chat to prevent a conversation taking place. That does not mean you can't actually comment, only that you shouldn't if it isn't totally necessary. But its probably that the WMIC of Windows 7 is not understanding the command and its syntax is different. What happens if you run `wmic sysdriver` in a command prompt on windows 7?

Comment: @ LPChip Thanks for the clarity. Wmic sysdriver in a cmd prompt on Windows7 works...

Comment: You should use a _backslash_ (```\```) as a path delimiter instead of _solidus_ (`/`).